# Page scrolls to top on every input blur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, native-base

I'm developing a simple app in `react-native` using `Expo` and `native-base`. I stumbled upon a problem about which I can't find any infomations in any documentation.

When I blur any text input, textarea etc. the page always scrolls to top rapidly. It only happens on iOS, on Android there is no such problem.

If this was asked before I'd really appreciate some clue what am I doing wrong.

I'm using following packages:

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
"react": "16.5.0",
"expo": "32.0.0",
"native-base": "^2.12.0"
```

Every page in my app is wrapped with following component:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { Container, Content } from "native-base";

const SceneWrapper = ({ Layout, bigTopPadding, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Container style={styles.container} >
      <Content style={styles.content} keyboardDismissMode="interactive">
        <Layout {...props} />
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "flex-start",
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  },
  content: {
    padding: 20,
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  }
});
```

I'm almost 100% sure that the `<Content>` component is at fault here, but I don't understand why and what should I change to prevent this. All I know is that `keyboardDismissMode` is not causing this problem, as it happened before I added this prop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, I managed to find solution for this.

I solved it by adding `enableResetScrollToCoords={false}` prop to `<Content>`.

Comment: saved hours of effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function l, which will be called on any input blur. Inside the function just call this method `window.scrollTo(0,0)`

Comment: It's react native. There is no window. Also, scrolling to `(0, 0)` was exactly what I wanted to prevent.